Who can be proud of whom? Is there any limit?
I can be proud of myself and my parents can be proud of me, etc. Can I be proud of someone I don't know, or have never met? I saw a comment on a YouTube (!) video where the commenter said about the video maker 'I'm so proud of you (for doing this etc...)' .

Yes, it sounded strange.

Someone might feel they know a Youtuber if they watch them a lot. People seem to post here a lot because they're upset with what people say on social media or other forums, but the beauty of social media and Youtube comments is that you can comment directly there if you're sufficiently troubled by what they say.

If you were asking whether people say such things -- is it idiomatic? -- the question would be on-topic; as it stands, it's an invitation to a debate about the nature of pride, and "taking pride", and thus off-topic.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question about language but about ideas, psychology, or even philosophy.

@AndyBonner It's entirely on-topic because it is about the semantics of the English word - there's no guarantee at all that other languages have the same range of applicability as 'pride' does in English.

As a matter of the meaning of the word proud, one can be proud only of something that one perceives as reflecting favourably on oneself. That most obviously includes one’s own achievements. It may also include something that is not directly one’s own, as long as one regards oneself as associated with it in some way that makes it reflect on oneself. Parents may thus be proud of the achievements of their children.
One can be proud of anything as long as this condition is satisfied. Often when we encounter the word proud it will be obvious how it is satisfied.  Somebody’s being proud of receiving a degree from a prestigious university, for example, does not require any explanation: that is clearly that person’s achievement. One’s being proud of one’s daughter receiving a degree from a prestigious university is also unproblematic, as the parent-child relationship is such that the achievements of the children are commonly regarded as reflecting on the parents. Somebody’s saying that he is proud of the sky would, however, be puzzling, but even that could be intelligible if it turns out that he believes that he has somehow prevented the sky from falling down. (Those who are familiar with the 20th century ethical theory will recognise that this example is borrowed from a 1959 article by Philippa Foot, ‘Moral Beliefs’.) If one claims to be proud of the achievements of somebody one is not obviously related to, we expect that it will be possible to get some explanation of how one sees oneself associated with that person, so that the achievement reflects on oneself. When people, for example, say that they are proud of the achievements of a particular sports team in an international competition, even though they have never met anybody who is on that team, we expect that this is because it is their country’s team, and because they believe that the achievements of a country’s team reflect on all of the country’s citizens. It should be emphasised that what is relevant here is how the person who is said to be proud perceives the relationship with the object of pride, not how other people may perceive similar relationships. But if no account of how what one is said to be proud of reflects favourably on oneself is available, even if only in one’s own mind, we would have to say that the word proud has been misused.
The use of the word proud in the OP’s example is puzzling, and in need of explanation. The explanation may or may not be available. It is possible that the people involved see themselves as somehow working together for the same cause, and see everything that advances the cause as reflecting on everyone involved; if so, it is intelligible that one of them would be proud of the achievements of the other. But if nothing like that is the case, then proud is the wrong word to use.


Who can be proud of whom? Is there any limit?

There is no limit.
Anyone or anything can be proud of anything or anyone.
The literal use is restricted to sentient beings (usually human) who have the ability to experience pride, but in metaphorical, or anthropomorphic use there is no restriction
From Nicander of Colophon's Theriaca: A Literary Commentary By Floris Overduin

661 [Greek word] see 100 n.


[Two Greek words]: the only two previous instances of the adj. [Greek word] are Hes. Th. 832 (of a bull, proud of his might), and Hdt. 7.57 (of Xerxes), although the variant without the prothetic alpha is more common. The adj. expresses an emotion that is either human (as in Hdt.), or is a projection of a human emotion on an animal (as in Hes.). Here, as in earlier instances, the projection of a human emotion is extended to a plant, which is said to be proud of its leaves. For the portrayal of plants showing human qualities see Introduction 8.i.


It is common both to speak of being proud of, and to be proud of (genuinely esteem), notable men and women throughout history ... and we speak also of being proud of their achievements and wholesome legacy. Examples include:


We should be proud of the Beckhams. It is time to celebrate a great British success story, exemplifying grace, dignity and humour when
such things are in short supply.


[Terence Blacker; 2023]


“... “We should be so proud of our great heroes in this nation like Winston Churchill...."


[Jacob Rees-Mogg; The Inverness Courier; 2020]


We should be proud of our Christian heritage, and we should remember our Christian values in the work that we do.


('Heritage' here refers to the lives of godly Christians over the last 2000+ years, and the good institutions they have instigated and championed: their legacy.)
[Nick Fletcher; 'Christianity'; 2023
(Of course, different people will assess the worth of different celebrities differently.)
Obviously, it would be infelicitous to use 'proud of' without careful consideration of the real merits of the people involved and the changes effected.
When it comes to addressing someone you've just met for the first time, who has done something undeniably laudable, it's unusual to use "I'm so proud of you." This is probably because it tends to come over as at best patronising or claiming a false familiarity with the addressee.
We'd likewise rarely say "I'm so proud of Isaac Newton" (though everyone agrees he was a truly remarkable man who advanced the sciences enormously). Because of the first person singular subject, there is an implied familiarity with the person being praised, which doesn't work well in this case. "Isaac Newton is a man we can/should all be proud of" work far better.
I'd just add that we can include animals that have performed remarkable feats:

I'm so proud of Prince. He found the injured hiker in the scrub, and then alerted us to the fact that something was amiss, and led us straight to him.

"I'm so proud of you, Prince[!]" will obviously not be regarded as over-familiar, especially if accompanied by a treat.
"I'm so proud of you, Derek[!]" needs a close relationship with the addressee, and even then a measure of delicacy.

'Notable men and women throughout history' and/or "There is an implied familiarity with the person being praised," I like these qualifications. I guess it's why the youtuber example sat awkwardly...

@flagflan Pride is personal emotion and saying you are proud of someone implies that you believe whatever they did (or are) has something to do with you. On the face of it, it seems a little delusional to be proud of a youtuber. Perhaps this person was a direct supporter e.g., through Patreon or believed they had some sort of impact on their success, however tangential.
